# Why does PHP overwrite values when I iterate through this array twice (by reference, by value)

Tags: php, php-5.3

If I iterate through an array twice, once by reference and then by value, PHP will overwrite the last value in the array if I use the same variable name for each loop. This is best illustrated through an example:

```
$array = range(1,5);
foreach($array as &$element)
{
  $element *= 2;
}
print_r($array);
foreach($array as $element) { }
print_r($array);
```

Output:

> Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 6 [3] => 8 **[4] => 10** )
>
> Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 6 [3] => 8 **[4] => 8** )

Note that I am not looking for a fix, I am looking to understand why this is happening. Also note that it does not happen if the variable names in each loop are not each called `$element`, so I'm guessing it has to do with `$element` still being in scope and a reference after the end of the first loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the first loop $element is still a reference to the last element/value of $array.
You can see that when you use var_dump() instead of print_r()

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
...
  [4]=>
  &int(2)
}
```

Note that & in `&int(2)`.
With the second loop you assign values to $element. And since it's still a reference the value in the array is changed, too. Try it with

```
foreach($array as $element)
{
  var_dump($array);
}
```

as the second loop and you'll see.
So it's more or less the same as

```
$array = range(1,5);
$element = &$array[4];
$element = $array[3];
// and $element = $array[4];
echo $array[4];
```

(only with loops and multiplication ...hey, I said "more or less" ;-))

Comment: Thanks! That makes complete sense.

Answer (score 5):

Here's [an explanation from the man himself](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50161):

> ```
> $y = "some test";
>
> foreach ($myarray as $y) {
>     print "$y\n";
> }
> ```
>
> Here `$y` is a symbol table entry referencing a string containing "some
>   test".  On the first iteration you essentially do:
>
> ```
> $y = $myarray[0];  // Not necessarily 0, just the 1st element
> ```
>
> So now the storage associated with `$y`
>   is overwritten by the value from
>   `$myarray`.  If `$y` is associated with
>   some other storage through a
>   reference, that storage will be
>   changed.
>
> Now let's say you do this:
>
> ```
> $myarray = array("Test");
> $a = "A string";
> $y = &$a;
>
> foreach ($myarray as $y) {
>     print "$y\n";
> }
> ```
>
> Here `$y` is associated with the same
>   storage as `$a` through a reference so
>   when the first iteration does:
>
> ```
> $y = $myarray[0];
> ```
>
> The only place that "Test" string can
>   go is into the storage associated with
>   `$y`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would fix this problem:

```
foreach($array as &$element)
{
    $element *= 2;
}
unset($element); #gets rid of the reference and cleans the var for re-use.

foreach($array as $element) { }
```