# Why? about PHP array and php foreach loop

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does PHP overwrite values when I iterate through this array twice (by reference, by value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645499/why-does-php-overwrite-values-when-i-iterate-through-this-array-twice-by-referen)

```
$arr=array('a','b','c');

foreach($arr as &$v){
    echo $v;
}

foreach($arr as $v){
    echo $v;
}
```

the result is abcabb, not abcabc, why?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does PHP overwrite values when I iterate through this array twice (by reference, by value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645499/why-does-php-overwrite-values-when-i-iterate-through-this-array-twice-by-referen)

Comment: Also plenty of discussion about it at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php