# php array gets screwed up by foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does PHP overwrite values when I iterate through this array twice (by reference, by value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645499/why-does-php-overwrite-values-when-i-iterate-through-this-array-twice-by-refere)

I got an array which if i print_r it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [product_id] => 13
            [1] => 1
            [account_id] => 1
            [vat type] => 0
            [vat included] => 0
            [price] => 3
            [unit] => test3
            [product number] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [product_id] => 12
            [1] => 1
            [account_id] => 1
            [vat type] => 1
            [vat included] => 0
            [price] => 2
            [unit] => test2
            [product number] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [product_id] => 11
            [1] => 1
            [account_id] => 1
            [vat type] => 2
            [vat included] => 0
            [price] => 1
            [unit] => test1
            [product number] => 1
        )
)
```

Now when i use a foreach to loop through it something weird happens. when i print_r each subarray in a foreach loop it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [product_id] => 13
    [1] => 1
    [account_id] => 1
    [vat type] => 0
    [vat included] => 0
    [price] => 3
    [unit] => test3
    [product number] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [product_id] => 12
    [1] => 1
    [account_id] => 1
    [vat type] => 1
    [vat included] => 0
    [price] => 2
    [unit] => test2
    [product number] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [product_id] => 12
    [1] => 1
    [account_id] => 1
    [vat type] => 1
    [vat included] => 0
    [price] => 2
    [unit] => test2
    [product number] => 2
)
```

Notice the 3th entry. It's a mysterie to me. Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Could you add your foreach code used to generate the second list please?

Comment: Can you show us your foreach code?

Comment: My money says you're reusing a referenced variable (`foreach ($array as &$foo)`)...

Answer (score 2):

the comment of 'deceze' pretty much solved the problem.
i used:

```
foreach($products as &$product){
```

and than added some entries to $product.
replacing that with:

```
foreach($products as $key=>$product){
```

and modifying $products[$key] solved the problem

Thanks =D

Comment: Or you can simply `unset($product)` after the loop, which you should anyway.